Ошибка: OSError: [WinError 64] Указанное сетевое имя более недоступно
Не получается подключиться к базе данных posrges. Ошибка:
OSError: [WinError 64] Указанное сетевое имя более недоступно
Мой код:
import asyncio
import asyncpg

async def run():
    # Подключение к базе данных
    conn = await asyncpg.connect(
        user='postgres',
        password='13243511',
        database='main',
        host='localhost',
        port=5432,
    )

"""
Указанные значения верны и совпадают со значениями 
в разделе connection в настройках бд
"""

try:
    # Выполнение запроса
    result = await conn.fetch('SELECT * FROM users')
    for record in result:
        print(record)
finally:
    # Закрытие подключения
    await conn.close()


asyncio.run(run())

